# Disable ssl in Keycloak 20.0.1

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to disable https:

I started the sever using `bin/kc.sh start-dev`

And then I tried to disable ssl using:

```
root@server:/opt/keycloak#
root@server:/opt/keycloak# /opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin –-password admin
Logging into http://locahost:8080/auth as user admin of realm master
Enter password: *****
null [RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token]
root@server:/opt/keycloak#
```

Do you know what is the proper way to execute the command?

PS:

Working commands:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user admin –-password admin
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot you can configure it in `application.yml`

```
keycloak:
  ssl-required: none
```

Since you're using Keycloak 20.0.1 you don't need `/auth` in server path, therefore, you need to modify command for configuring Keycloak as shown bellow:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user admin –-password admin
```

After that you should be able to disable SSL:

```
/opt/keycloak/bin/kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

Comment: I don't use Spring Boot. I get `root@server:/opt/keycloak# bin/kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
No server specified. Use --server, or 'kcadm.sh config credentials or connection'.
root@server:/opt/keycloak#`

Comment: In that case my guess is that the problem is with including `/auth` in server path. I've updated my answer

Comment: Commands are correct. Thank  you!